# How to combine REGEXP_CONTAINS

Tags: regex, google-bigquery

I have the following regex which works fine:

```
CASE WHEN
REGEXP_CONTAINS(Landing Page, '.*/ways-to-watch($|/.*)') THEN "Ways to Watch" ELSE "All"
END
```

However I'm wondering if there's a way to combine two or more of the rule above, for example if i can add to it:

```
REGEXP_CONTAINS(Landing Page, '.*/movies($|/.*)') THEN "Movies" ELSE "All"
```

How can I merge both into the same formula?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

...i'm not familiar with google bigquery, but have you tried to combine them on the query level instead of the regex level? sth in the lines of

```
CASE 
WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(Landing Page, '.*/ways-to-watch($|/.*)') THEN "Ways to Watch" 
WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(Landing Page, '.*/movies($|/.*)') THEN "Movies"
ELSE "All"
END
```

see https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/conditional_expressions